# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to get string information from a tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I have been working on this little bit of code for a school project extension and I cant seem to find a solution to this. I have so far been attempting to get the new user sign up system working and have stopped working on the login part of the program due to this issue. here is my code:

```
def newUser():
    usernameTemp = entryNew.get()
    passwordTemp = entryNewPass.get()

    database = {}

    addFile = open("database.txt", "a")
    addFile.write(usernameTemp + "," + passwordTemp + "\n")
    addFile.close()

def userValidation():
    global entryNew
    global entryNewPass
    global valid
    fileCheck = open("database.txt", "r")
    fileCheckData = fileCheck.read()
    fileCheck.close()

    entryNew = entryNew.get()
    entryNewPass = entryNewPass.get()

    database = {}

    for line in fileCheckData.splitlines():
        if line != '':           # ignore empty lines
            (username,password) = line.split(",", 1)
            database[username] = password
            if entryNew == username:
                Error(101)
                valid = False
            if valid == True:
                newUser()
                break
```

here is the database.txt file:

```
######################,#############
testUser,password
admin,administratorPass
```

Comment: Post your code **here**, not in a pastebin. Please reduce it to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That means you need to include the full traceback of the error too, don't have us guess where in a 175-line script your exception occurs and how you trigger it.

Comment: I've reopened this as you at least cut this back to a smaller amount of code. We are still missing the full traceback, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the `entryNew` and `entryNewPass` variables here:

```
global entryNew
global entryNewPass

entryNew = entryNew.get()
entryNewPass = entryNewPass.get()
```

You declared these global, so you replaced the object that has a `.get()` method (a TkInter entry box?) with a string.

Use different names for these variables:

```
entry = entryNew.get()
```

and use those new names in your function:

```
if entry == username:
```

You were not actually using `entryNewPass` anywhere in your code.